# Killing a running process in an Ubuntu machine remotely from a windows machine which is in LAN

Tags: linux, process, windows

Is it possible to kill a process running in an Ubuntu machine from a Windows (XP) machine remotely connected via LAN?

I can kill the process in a windows machine from a remote windows machine (in LAN) by the following command:

```
taskkill /S system /U username /P password  /IM process.exe
```

Is there any thing like that to kill the process running on the Linux machine?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/8937/67621

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have SSH or Telnet access to the Linux machine?  (Typically, SSH is more reliable in trouble situations, but either can work.)

Login, use `top`, `ps`, or `pgrep` to get the process id (pid) of whatever needs killing, and then kill away with `kill PID` or `kill -9 PID` on the command line.  If you have a new enough system, you can even kill processes from within `top` by choosing one and pressing 'k'.

Furthermore, `ssh` and `rsh` can be used to remotely execute commands without the whole interactive login session, if that's what you end up needing in the future:

```
$ ssh USER@HOSTNAME COMMAND
```

Comment: +1, and I just want to add that on Windows, you can use PuTTY to ssh to a Linux/Unix machine http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: I would just note that you want to avoid `kill -9` if you can.  Try `kill PID` twice, then try `kill -INT PID` before trying `kill -9`.  SIGKILL is untrappable and thus doesn't allow the program to clean up after itself.

Comment: You're right.  Of course, I find `kill -9` satisfying when angry.  ;D

Comment: Better not use telnet; your password will be send in the clear.  (although if you LAN only has completely trusted people on it, it won't hurt).

Comment: Seriously?  Let the admin worry 'bout that.  If he's still got `rlogin` available, he might as well use it.  :P

Answer (score 1):

Windows has these tools for remote management built-in to the shell.  For remote management of a *nix host, you need to get a shell on the remote host.  As suggested above, you need an ssh client of some sort.  You can use a windowed application like putty (linked above), or there is a native port of openssh for win32 that doesn't require cygwin.  You can find it here: http://www.nomachine.com/contributions.